# how to store values in session properly

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I have these pages that asks user for values. when I try to use the links to previous pages, the session values are gone and it requires user to go back to the first and repeat the process.

Here are sample codes based of my original code:

page1.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo "<form method='POST' action='page2.php'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='date1'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='date2'>";
    echo "<input type='submit'>"
 echo "</form>";
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['date1'] = $_POST['date1'];
 $_SESSION['date2'] = $_POST['date2'];
      echo "<form method='POST' action='page3.php'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='info1'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='info2'>";
        echo "<input type='submit'>"
     echo "</form>";
echo "<a href='page1.php'>Change value in page 1</a>";
?>
```

page3.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['info1'] = $_POST['info1'];
 $_SESSION['info2'] = $_POST['info2'];
 if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';
$db = 'sampDB';

$conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db);

$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'INSERT INTO info(date1, date2, info1, info2)
                               VALUE ('$_SESSION[date1]', '$_SESSION[date2]', '$_SESSION[info1]', '$_SESSION[info2]')');

}
      echo "<form method='POST'>";
        echo $_SESSION['date1'];
        echo $_SESSION['date2'];
        echo $_SESSION['info1'];
        echo $_SESSION['info2'];
        echo "<input type='submit' name='confirm'>"
     echo "</form>";
echo "<a href='page1.php'>Change value in page 1</a>";
echo "<a href='page2.php'>Change value in page 2</a>";
?>
```

How do I go back to previos pages without destroying the values from the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're not `$_POST`ing values back to the other pages, you can simply check if `$_POST` is set before overwriting values, like so:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["date1"])) $_SESSION['date1'] = $_POST['date1'];
if(isset($_POST["date2"])) $_SESSION['date2'] = $_POST['date2'];
```

---

*Reference: [PHP `isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)*

Comment: I tried `$_SESSION['date1']  = isset($_POSTS['date1']) ? $_POSTS['date1'] : '';` not sure why i did not work

Comment: @chemical_elii It won't work because if the `$_POST` value isn't set, it'll make the `$_SESSION` value blank. You don't want to affect the `$_SESSION` value if `$_POST` is not set!

Answer (score 0):

Everytime, you are overwriting values of SESSION.

You need to check whether session is already set.

If already set, then there should be not change.

Also, posted values should be applied only if form is posted.

Add checks if sessions already exist like this:

```
$_SESSION['date1'] = !isset($_SESSION['date1']) ? $_POST['date1'] : 
$_SESSION['date1'];

$_SESSION['date2'] = !isset($_SESSION['date2']) ? $_POST['date2'] : $_SESSION['date2'];
```

Same for other session values.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your query this way

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO info(date1, date2, info1, info2) 
VALUE ('{$_SESSION['date1']}', '{$_SESSION['date2']}', 
    '{$_SESSION['info1']}', '{$_SESSION['info2']}')");
```